# Express, diff between route.use() ,route.all(),route.route()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If `router.all()` just match all methods,could it be instead by `router.use()`?
and what `router.use()` diff between `router.route()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`router.all()` matches every http protocol, `router.use()` is for middleware, and `router.route()` returns an instance of a single route which you can then use to handle HTTP verbs with optional middleware.
You should check out the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html) for more informations

Comment: I still confuse,1: what diff between router.all('/url',fun) and router.use('/url',fun) in fact? does they has same effect in project?
2:router.route() how it can option middleware?

Comment: Depending on the request you want, you'll send the appropriate request. For example if you want to send form data to the server you can use POST request, and then your route will be `route.post('/abc',fn) `. Or if you need to update something on DB then you'll use PUT request.
I suggest you see this tutorial about http request to fully understand how this works https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm

Comment: router.use() is to basically set options to your project

Answer (score 10):

**router.all**: What this means is, it doesn't matter the method of the request.. (post, get, put), if the url matches, execute the function.

ex- router.all("/abc",fn) will be work for all request to /abc

**router.use()** : router.use() helps you write modular routes and modules.. You basically define a middle ware for routes.

router.use("/pqr", pqrRoutes)

now for all requests that start with /pqr like /pqr/new or /pqr/xyz can be handles inside the pqrRoutes.

**router.route()**: this is nice way to define the different Method implementations for a single url end point.

lets just say you have two api end points. router.get("/jkl") and router.post("/jkl"), with router.route() you cam sort of combine these different api handlers..

you can say router.route("/jkl").get(fn1).post(fn2)

Comment: For the router.all does you mean that the router.all("/abc",fn) does not match  /abc/etc ?

Answer (score 0):

app.all(), which is not derived from any HTTP method. This method is used for loading middleware functions at a path for all request methods.

```
app.all('/secret', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Accessing the secret section ...')
  next() // pass control to the next handler
})
```

Use the express.Router class to create modular, mountable route handlers. A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason, it is often referred to as a “mini-app”.

The following example creates a router as a module, loads a middleware function in it, defines some routes, and mounts the router module on a path in the main app.

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
```

Bascially we use .use when we use a middleware
express.Router

Use the express.Router class to create modular, mountable route handlers. A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason, it is often referred to as a “mini-app”.

The following example creates a router as a module, loads a middleware function in it, defines some routes, and mounts the router module on a path in the main app.
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

```
// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
```

There can we more than 1 router this instance of router has name router defined below the express defination.
Here is the documentation for router
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

***`Router.use()`***

Routers behave like middleware and can be `.use()d` by the app in other routers. In other words, routers allow you to chunk your big app into numerous mini-apps that you can later put together. For small apps, this might be overkill, but as soon as you think, “This `app.js` file is getting big,” it’s time to think about breaking down your app with routers.

***`router.route(path)`***

The `router.route(path)` method is used to chain HTTP verb methods. For example, in a create, read, update, and
delete (CRUD) server that has POST, GET, PUT, and DELETE endpoints for the /posts/:id URL (e.g., /posts/53fb401
dc96c1caa7b78bbdb), we can use the Router class as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.param('postId', function(request, response, next) {
// Find post by ID
// Save post to request
request.post = {
 name: 'Node.js',
 url: 'http://your-url/node-js-blog'
   };
return next();
});
```

The `Router.route(path)` method provides the convenience of chaining methods, which is a more appealing way
to structure, your code than re-typing router for each route.
Alternatively, we can use `router.VERB(path, [callback...], callback)` to define the routes just as we
would use `app.VERB()`. Similarly, the `router.use()` and `router.param()` methods work the same as `app.use()` and
`app.param()`.